# Maximum number of nodes which can be reached from each node in a graph using igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to find the maximum number of nodes which can be reached from each node in a graph using igraph in R.

For example, I have the following graph:

IGRAPH fb9255f DN-- 4 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), X (e/l)
+ edges from fb9255f (vertex names):
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqSe5.png) 1->2 2->3 2->4

[Resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqSe5.png)

For node 1, for example, I would like to obtain the list of all the possible
nodes reachable (not only using one hop) from it.

In this case, for node 1 it will be: [2,3,4]

I have read the igraph documentation, but I do not see any function that can help.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Carlos

Answer (score 1):

You can compute this using the `subcomponent` function.

Since you do not provide any data, I will illustrate with an arbitrary example.

```
## Example graph
library(igraph)
set.seed(123)
g = erdos.renyi.game(15, 0.15, directed = TRUE)
plot(g)
```

[image: A directed graph]

`subcomponent` gives you all of nodes that are reachable.  Here, I am assuming that you are using directed graphs and you mean reachable by going forward along the directed edges. You can change this by altering the `mode` argument to `subcomponent`.

```
sort(subcomponent(g, 2, mode="out"))
+ 7/15 vertices:
[1]  2  5 10 12 13 14 15
```

If you just want the number of nodes that can be reached, just take the length

```
length(subcomponent(g, 2, mode="out"))
[1] 7
```

Comment: @ G5W: Is it possible to add a "degree" argument here? e.g. how many nodes can you reach from "2" having degree 0,1,2,3?

Comment: @stats_noob  It would be easy to compute that with an extra line or so of code.  Please ask this as a new question and refer to this one as context. If you direct me to your new question,  I will answer there.

Comment: @ G5W: Thank you for your reply! I have created this new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608018/r-all-nodes-of-degree-n-that-can-be-reached-from-some-node